# Why does the DOM single-origin policy take into account protocol and port? What if it was just domain?

Tags: security, dom, networking

I'm learning the basics of network security and am trying to really understand the single origin policy. I was wondering what the vulnerabilities would be if an origin was only defined by domain, as opposed to the normal trio of scheme, domain, host. I know it would be more insecure, but how exactly?

My thinking was, for protocol, the dangers of sending/receiving data from an https page to an http one, since when something coming from the http page wouldn't be encrypted and could be read by someone monitoring network traffic. I'm not really sure if that's correct reasoning or not.

As for the need for the port in origin definition, I don't really have any ideas.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would better fit on https://security.stackexchange.com/